# What is the correct term for the "destination/tail" vertex of a directed edge?

Tags: graph-theory

Non-mathematician here, trying to design a computer program with a directed graph as the underlying data model. I'd like to make sure that when I name things in the program, I have a way to refer to the beginning or ending vertex of any given edge - in a way that's in accordance with mathematical best practices. For instance, `edge.getDestinationVertex` vs. `edge.getTail`. Are head/tail the correct term from a mathematical perspective? It's a bit difficult to search Google for this answer! Thanks in advance for helping with a newbie question.

Comment: For a directed edge/arc/arrow $e = (u,v)$, which goes from $u$ to $v$, we call $u$ the tail and $v$ the head, exactly as you would draw an arrow from $u$ to $v$, i.e. $u \to v$. See also: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Directed_graph) and [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirectedGraph.html).

Comment: @dtldarek Currently, your Wolfram link makes no mention of "tail" and "head", but instead uses the terms "source" and "sink" in the figure.